# File Selection / Folder Selection supporting Drag'n'Drop

Tags: desktop-application, selection, file-input

First of all, I personally really dislike the folder browse dialog where you cannot copy/paste the folder name which you might already have in the clipboard.

In many cases for my own applications I see myself writing the same code over and over, which is:

- a textbox which holds the folder name. The user can copy/paste the folder name here.
- the textbox supports drag'n'drop and it will accept directories being dropped.
- the textbox gets colored depending if the folder exists or not to give immediate feedback (just in the cases I want it to be existent)
- a button labelled "...". This opens a **File**BrowseDialog. The filename is "file name will be ignored. The CheckFileExists property is set to *false*.

Now I'm going to put this into a reusable Control and as I want to do it right,

**these are my questions**

- While I'm personally fine with the file open dialog, what misunderstandings could arise from this approach? (Because actually the user will select a directory, not a file)
- Should I allow drag'n'dropping files onto the textbox and then extract the directory name from the file name?
- What would be best if the user tries to drop multiple files or folders?

Please do not only give your opinion, also try to mention a design principle which is followed or not followed.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold for now. You're asking too many questions within one post - which is also one reason you may not have had any answers so far either. Each post should be **one distinct question** that can be explicitly answered. If you can reformat your post accordingly we can reopen it.